# How to execute stored procedure in ASP.NET Core 3.1 and assign result sets to variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, dapper

I am new to ASP.NET Core (3.1). I have a stored procedure that takes two parameters: `startDate` and `endDate`.

It returns the following result sets in one go (or execution):

[image]

I want to be able to grab the result sets in 3 separate variables because I will like to output them on my view:

For example - for the 1st result set:

```
foreach (var maindata in Model.MainDataViewModel)
{
     <td>maindata.CaseId</td>
     <td>maindata.EpisodeId</td>
     <td>maindata.SpecimenTag</td>
     <td>maindata.PathologyOrderId</td>
}
```

Likewise for the second and third.

I have attempted to call the stored procedure using this code:

```
public SpPotentialCandidatesForOncotypeDXViewModel GetPotentialCandidatesForTheOncotypeDXData(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    try
    {
        List<SqlParameter> pc = new List<SqlParameter>
                        {
                           new SqlParameter("@p0", startDate),
                           new SqlParameter("@p1", endDate),
                        };
        
        var da = _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("spPotentialCandidatesForOncotypeDX @p0, @p1", pc.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppLog.WriteError("GetPotentialCandidatesForTheOncotypeDXData", ex.Message);
    }

    // return spPotentialCandidatesForOncotypeDXes;
}
```

After testing, `da` has value -1. Via further research I realise `ExecuteSqlRaw` returns the number of rows affected and not the result sets.

How can I capture these result sets individually and assign to variables?

Comment: Not natively supported (issue is still "Open" https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8127) - but if you just do a search of SO for "entity framework core multiple result sets" there are a handful of workaround suggestions

Comment: Use Dapper, or do the `SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**ExecuteSqlRaw** is used for executing SQL commands that do not return entities, but affect rows (like UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE). If you want to capture result sets, you would typically use a method like **FromSqlRaw**.

Given your needs, here's how you can do it:

Define your ViewModel classes to map the results of the stored procedure:

```
public class MainDataViewModel
{
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public int EpisodeId { get; set; }
    public string SpecimenTag { get; set; }
    public int PathologyOrderId { get; set; }
}

public class SecondDataViewModel
{
    // Define properties similar to MainDataViewModel based on your second result set
}

public class ThirdDataViewModel
{
    // Define properties similar to MainDataViewModel based on your third result set
}

public class SpPotentialCandidatesForOncotypeDXViewModel
{
    public List<MainDataViewModel> MainDataViewModels { get; set; }
    public List<SecondDataViewModel> SecondDataViewModels { get; set; }
    public List<ThirdDataViewModel> ThirdDataViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

Execute the stored procedure and map results to your ViewModel classes:

```
public SpPotentialCandidatesForOncotypeDXViewModel GetPotentialCandidatesForTheOncotypeDXData(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var model = new SpPotentialCandidatesForOncotypeDXViewModel();

    try
    {
        var pc = new List<SqlParameter>
        {
            new SqlParameter("@p0", startDate),
            new SqlParameter("@p1", endDate),
        };

        model.MainDataViewModels = _dbContext.Set<MainDataViewModel>()
            .FromSqlRaw("spPotentialCandidatesForOncotypeDX @p0, @p1", pc.ToArray()).ToList();

        // Assuming the stored procedure returns 3 separate result sets, you'll need to modify the stored procedure and execute it three times
        // for the 3 different data mappings.

        // model.SecondDataViewModels = _dbContext.Set<SecondDataViewModel>().FromSqlRaw("YourProcedureForSecondData @p0, @p1", pc.ToArray()).ToList();
        // model.ThirdDataViewModels = _dbContext.Set<ThirdDataViewModel>().FromSqlRaw("YourProcedureForThirdData @p0, @p1", pc.ToArray()).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppLog.WriteError("GetPotentialCandidatesForTheOncotypeDXData", ex.Message);
    }

    return model;
}
```

Then in your View, use the returned model as you demonstrated in your question.

**Note**: The example assumes that the stored procedure will be executed three times for the three different data mappings. If your stored procedure returns 3 result sets in one go, then this method won't work and you'd have to look into more specialized methods or libraries to handle multiple result sets with Entity Framework Core.